# Two assumptions of machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Some time ago I read about the two assumptions of machine learning:

1. Data input has a correlation with data output.
2. Enough data is present to find it

However, I don't know, where I read it and I want to cite it in my thesis. Can give me a reference in literature?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn´t seem like a ML assumption. This is what you would like. Are you sure that you want to add that to a thesis?

Comment: Well, if you don't assume that this is the case, then your machine learning couldn't find anything to begin with.